# Correct way to implement 1 to 0..1 relation in relational databases

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

Imagine, in our data model we have an entity (a data structure), which has optional parts. We can implement those "parts" as nullable references to other (child) entities. In other words, each instance of the master entity may have or not have a single instance of other (child) entity associated with it, and any instance of child entity has only one instance of master entity associated with it. So we have 1 to 0..1 relation.

For example, an audit log record has common fields like (timestamp, user, operation) and also operation-specific part (extended information), which can be completely different for different operations. We can use separate entity to represent each type of extended info, then make the master entity have nullable references to each possible type of extended info.

I can see 2 ways of implementing it in relational databases:

## 1. Nullable references to child entities in master record

For each type of child entity, the master record table has a field referencing the ID of a record from child (extension) table as a foreign key.

This seems to be more straightforward option: to retrieve related information we just follow the direct reference. In SQL query we will left-join child (extension) tables by the foreign key. Null values of the foreign key will give us null values for all the child tables' fields.

## 2. Child entitys' records reference master entity's records

We do not store any references in the master entity table. Instead, each record of child entity table(s) references a record from the master table by ID as a foreign key. In SQL query we still left-join child tables to the master one, and we get null values for all the child tables' fields where there is no corresponding child record.

## ???

Which approach is the correct one? The 2nd one seems to be more **relational**, and we do not have to create extra fields in the master table, but technically it may require more work to find the related records, because instead of following direct references we have to search for master ID in child tables. Or do DB engines optimize this kind of joins to be quick, e.g. using indexes? The index search is faster then scan, but still slower then direct reference. Plus indexes take space. I fill lack of knowledge in how DB engines work... Or maybe I just miss something obvious. Help will be much appreciated.

## Update

After getting the answer below, and also having some more thinking, and decided to use the 2nd approach. In addition to what was said in the accepted answer (more compact, more correct from relational perspective, does not have to deal with NULLs), it also gives me nice possibility to use cascaded deletion if I need to delete the master recods with all corresponding child records.

Comment: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461/266284)

Comment: @philipxy Thank you for the comment, though it is not helpful. I know this may look like an opinion-based question, but it is actually not. I believe there is a correct and incorrect way of doing this, I just do not know, which is correct. I have edited the question to remove "best practice" trigger words.

Comment: Your post does not ask an answerable question because it does not give sufficient detail or criteria for a choice. There is no question for you to not know the answer to. You are just wondering amid a few observations.

Comment: Philip's comments are incorrect, you can disregard them.  You are correct, you have given a single problem with two examples.  There are many ways to solve or partially solve this single problem ... but there is just one Relational (scientifically correct) way.  The problem however is, that people who do not know the science will perceive this as an "opinion-based" question.  Such as philip's comment, and the vote to close the question.

Comment: Observe that the accepted answer post does not answer the question you asked & says it can't be answered, and repeats my comment re "best".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this I think that an “optimal” solution depends on the workload of the database, since both solutions have strengths and weaknesses.

The second solution has no null values, which often complicates the queries (and the null values also make a solution non “correct” for the purists of the relational model), but has also other benefits: it requires less space (so that the relations are more compact and require less time to be operated on, for certain types of operations). On the other hand, it requires joins to access detailed data (and so it requires an extra index for those operations).

The first solution is conceptually more simple, does not require joins in case of accessing detailed data, but requires more space, and this can slow down certain types of operations.

Both solutions are used in practical contexts.

I think that a solution to this dilemma can be provided only by knowing which is the typical workload of the application that must be deployed over such database: are more frequent (or must have less latency) certain queries with respect to others? For instance, queries that look only the general data are used more often that queries that require detailed data?

Finally, if it is difficult or impossible to do such “theorical” analysis, the only other way is to try one solution, but being prepared to try also the other if the performances are not satisfying. This can be done by using views, for instance in this way:

1. Start with the second solution, and define a view that does the join.
2. Write the application by using, when appropriate, either the base table or the join view.
3. If the performances are not satisfying, switch to the other solution by creating a new table by join, with the same name of the old view, and define a new view that perform just a projection on the not null attributes.

By exchanging the same names for the views and the base table in the two cases, the application will require only a minimum set of modifications, and you can experiment with both approaches.